# Exclude the O,o and 0 from wordpress passwords

Tags: php, wordpress

My client wants to take out the possibility of the clients to use Os and 0-s in the passwords for registration (because of the similarities how they look alike).

Is it possible somehow, with some hook?

Comment: small L (I) and capital i (I) looks same too

Comment: You can change the font-family.

Comment: Have you thought about telling your client that this is a bad idea?

Comment: You should only apply this if you are randomly generating the passwords. Generally if people want an O or an 0 somewhere in their password they will remember it's in there. Restricting users in making their own passwords is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `preg_match`, `[0oO]` matches a single character

```
if (!preg_match('/[0oO]/g',$password)) {
    echo "password doesn't contain '0', 'o' or 'O'.";
} else {
    echo "password contains '0', 'o' or 'O'.";
}
```

see [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

**€dit**: i don't recommend that, it is a restriction for the user and it make the password less secure.